# Syntax Error when working with Window Functions in DBeaver

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions, dbeaver

I'm trying to write window function in SQL (I use DBeaver). The script is pretty simple, however, I'm getting the error

```
SQL Error: Syntax error: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 4, column 20.
Was expecting:
  <EOF>
```

The code:

```
SELECT
  Athlete,
  Event,
  row_number() OVER() AS num
FROM summer;
```

I'm new to SQL, so any help would be important for me

Comment: Hi, can you specify what database do you use? (PostgreSQL, Oracle etc). It seems that it doesn't like how you wrote the window function ?

Comment: @F.Lazarescu I installed SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an old version of SQLite.  This code works fine:

```
create table summer (
    athlete int,
    event int
);

SELECT
  Athlete,
  Event,
  row_number() over () AS num
FROM summer;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1ac9698f575f788767483a000a2307ae) is a db<>fiddle.

Window functions were introduced in version 3.25.  You can check your version using:

```
 select sqlite_version();
```

Note that the SQL Standard specifies that the `ORDER BY` is required for `ROW_NUMBER()`.  In SQLite (and some other databases), it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite it seems that you don't need the parentheses after "over".
So it will be like this:

```
SELECT
  Athlete,
  Event,
  row_number() OVER AS num
FROM summer;
```

[Source](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, it doesn't work. Probably, I've mislead you. I installed SQLite indeed, however, I work with csv file right now, that i connected as (i guess) a database. So, csv file is placed below "Dbeaver Sample Dataset (SQLite)"